# Ionsiation enthalpy of Zinc Cadmium and Mercury

Tags: ionization-energy

Why is ionisation enthalpy of Zinc, Cadmium and Hg in the increasing order, when ideally, all periodic groups have decreasing order of enthalpy downward?

An argument could be that F and D orbitals show less screening effect, but this is true for all the transition metal groups.

Another argument about fully filled shells being more stable also arises,... but even 3rd, 4th and 5th groups have fully filled S shells. When it comes to D orbitals, how does it being fully filled affect the ionisation enthalpy? It is not the valence shell afterall.